# SQL Server: how to remove last comma after combining rows using XML Path

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

I found a way to combine multiple row's into one row which is comma separated but now I would like to remove the last comma.

```
CREATE TABLE supportContacts 
(
   id int identity primary key, 
   type varchar(20), 
   details varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO supportContacts (type, details)
VALUES ('Email', 'admin@sqlfiddle.com'),
       ('Twitter', '@sqlfiddle');
```

This query combines types, but I want to now remove the last comma:

```
SELECT top (2) 
    type + ', ' AS 'data()'
FROM  
    supportContacts
ORDER BY 
    type DESC
FOR XML PATH('')
```

This is the current result:

```
Twitter, Email,
```

Comment: In a pinch, you can use substring, to delete the last character ;)

Comment: @okaram will that work if I don't know how long the string will be?  Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare  @BigStrRes8K nvarchar(4000) 

SELECT @BigStrRes8K = ( SELECT top (2) [type] + ', ' AS 'data()'
FROM supportContacts 
ORDER BY type DESC
FOR XML PATH('') ) 

SELECT LEFT(RTRIM(@BigStrRes8K), ( LEN(RTRIM(@BigStrRes8K))) - 1) as FinalNoComma
```

I would never do this where I controlled the render code.  I would teach the caller to handle the trailing comma.  Also you have to allow for nulls and the 4K or 8K limit of SQL rows

Answer (score 21):

While you already have an answer, another common idiom that you'll see is:

```
select stuff((
    SELECT top (2) 
        ', ' type AS 'data()'
    FROM  
        supportContacts
    ORDER BY 
        type DESC
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 2, '')
```

This says "take the result of the select and replace the two characters starting at position 1 with a zero-length string".

Comment: I strongly prefer using STUFF than trying to combine LTRIM/RTRIM/LEN/etc.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me->

1.Inserting comma Before Data

2.Using Stuff to Remove it

```
select (stuff((
   SELECT ', '+ Name  AS 'data()' 
   FROM Table_1 
   FOR XML PATH('')),
   Count('ID')
, 1, ' '))as Result
```